# Kohana ORM order_by a query

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-orm

I'm looking for the best way to order a result set based on the 'most viewed' count of another table?

I have a products table and a history table. The history table stores the view count of the products and is linked in by the product_id.

What is the best way to order the product listing by the 'view_count' column in the history table?

Thanks for help with this.

Comment: Share your DB schema for the tables involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a one-to-one- relationship between `products` and `history` the query would be something like:

```
SELECT products.* FROM products
INNER JOIN history on products.id = history.products_id
ORDER BY history.view_count DESC
```

If there are multiple `history` records for each `product` than its a different scenario. This might not scale, you might consider adding the `view_count` to `products` and just incrementing it on each view.